# Relation between Levi-Civita tensor and the trace of Lorentz transformations

Tags: tensor-calculus, supersymmetry, lorentz-symmetry, spinors

here is this tricky identity to prove in an appendix of W.B. Supersymmetry and Supergravity that's driving me crazy. Some premises first:

This book use the van der Waerden's convention for spinor indices, where bispinors transforming in $\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$ and $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ of SO(1,3) are indicated rispectively as:
$$\delta\psi_\alpha=\frac{i}{2}{\left(\omega_{\mu\nu}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\right)_\alpha}^\beta\psi_\beta,\quad
\delta\bar{\psi}^\dot{\alpha}=\frac{i}{2}{\left(\omega_{\mu\nu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu\nu}\right)^\dot{\alpha}}_\dot{\beta}\bar{\psi}^\dot{\beta}$$
with ($\alpha=1,2$), and:
$${{\sigma^{\mu\nu}}_\alpha}^\beta=\frac{1}{4}{\left(\sigma^\mu\bar{\sigma}^\nu-\sigma^\nu\bar{\sigma}^\nu\right)_\alpha}^\beta\\
{{\bar{\sigma}^{\mu\nu}}^\dot{\alpha}}_\dot{\beta}=\frac{1}{4}{\left(\bar{\sigma}^\mu\sigma^\nu-\bar{\sigma}^\nu\sigma^\nu\right)^\dot{\alpha}}_\dot{\beta}$$
The similarity transformation between the fundamental and anti-fundamental is given by:
$$\psi^\alpha=\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\psi_\beta,\quad
\bar{\psi}_\dot{\alpha}=\varepsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}\bar{\psi}^\dot{\beta}\\
{\bar{\sigma}^\mu}^{\dot{\alpha}\beta}=\varepsilon^{\beta\gamma}\varepsilon^{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\lambda}}\sigma^\mu_{\gamma\dot{\lambda}}\\ \sigma^\mu=(-\mathbb{I},\sigma^i)$$
where the $\sigma^i$ are Pauli's matrices and Levi-Civita's tensor $\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}$ has signature $\varepsilon^{12}=\varepsilon_{21}=1$ so that $\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\varepsilon_{\beta\gamma}=\delta^\alpha_\gamma$.

Now the above mentioned identity is:
$$\diamondsuit \quad \mathrm{Tr}\left(\sigma^{\mu\nu}\sigma^{\rho\tau}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\tau}-\eta^{\mu\tau}\eta^{\nu\rho}\right)-\frac{i}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\tau}$$
where the signatures of the flat metric and Levi-Civita tensor are:
$$\eta^{\mu\nu}=(-,+,+,+)\;,\quad \varepsilon^{0123}=-1$$
I understant why $\diamondsuit$ must have this form: $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ and $\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\tau}$ are the only tensors with the correct index permutation structure and invariance under Lorentz, but can't obtain it more rigorously. Can you give me some help? Thank you in advance.

**P.S.** Position, geography of contraction and dotting of spinor indices are very important in this notation, with the only exception of $\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}$ which always contract with the most left index.

Comment: I do not know your exact circumstance, but in Penrose's notation if you have a basis of the two-spinor space, $\omicron^\bullet, \iota^\bullet: ~~\epsilon_{AB}\omicron^A\iota^B=\sqrt{1/2}$ then the Hermitian matrices over the two-spinors are a $(+---)$ Minkowski space, with Pauli matrices $$w^a=\omicron^A\omicron^{\dot A}+\iota^A\iota^{\dot A}\\x^a=\omicron^A\iota^{\dot A}+\iota^A\omicron^{\dot A}\\y^a=i~\omicron^A\iota^{\dot A}-i~\iota^A\omicron^{\dot A}\\z^a=\omicron^A\omicron^{\dot A}-\iota^A\iota^{\dot A}$$ being a 4-basis and $\eta^{ab}=\epsilon^{AB}\epsilon^{\dot A\dot B}$ the metric.

Comment: Well, that's true, and in van der Waerden's notation your suggestion can be translated in the map from Minkowsky space and the space of hermitian matrices whose determinant is conserved by SL(2,$\mathbb{C}$) similarity transformation (aka Lorentz) as:$$v^\mu\rightarrow v_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}=v^\mu {\sigma_\mu}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}$$ but i don't get how can It be related to the identity that's obsessing me, sorry :P

Comment: For a proof of this identity, consult "Supersymmetry: An Introduction with Conceptual and Calculational Details" by A. Wiedemann and Harald J. W. Mueller-Kirsten, page 84.